# CI: Illegal string offset Warning in php 7.1 or higher

Tags: php, codeigniter

I work on CI 3.1.7 php 7.0 and when i upgrade my php version to 7.1.13 and 7.2 i got this error in Codeigniter.

**Note: it will work fine in php 7.0.**

controller code:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
public $data="";
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    //var_dump($this->site_model->get_web_data(1));die();
    $this->data["C_mobile_number"]=$this->site_model->get_web_data(1);
```

model code

```
function get_web_data($id){

    $result=$this->db->where('drid',$id)
                ->get('web_data');
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        $data=$result->result();    
        return $data[0]->data;
    }else{
        return "";
    }


}
```

var_dump result :  `E:\wamp64\www\**\application\controllers\Site.php:9:string '+91.**********' (length=14)`

In php 7.1 or higher i got this error

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'C_mobile_number'
>
> Filename: controllers/Site.php Line Number: 10

Any salution?

Answer (score 3):

Before `$this->data["C_mobile_number"]=...` insert `$this->data = [];`.
This is initiated `$this->data` as array;

Comment: Thanx it works can you please tell me for my knowledge why it works in php 7.0 and why it does not work in php 7.1 or higher

Comment: In php 7.1 is higher typing requirements.

Comment: @Rohankumar If I helped you - please mark my answer as useful. Press Up arrow.

Comment: I definitely want to do this for you. but i have only 11 reputations and i need 15 to do this. I think you now how StackOverflow work

Comment: @Rohankumar Now you have 16.

Comment: @Rohankumar Thank you!